# How to spread out my navigation bar, I have display:flex in my code

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tags, uinavigationbar

I've been trying to spread out my navigation bar I just can't seem to do it, I have display: flex; on, with justify-content: space-around, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

https://codepen.io/picklemyrickle/pen/XWjzyvb

Thanks in advance.

```
<nav id="nav-bar">
<ul>
  <li> <a 
       class="nav-link" 
       href=#Programs
       id="Programs">
    Programs </a></li>
    
 <li> <a 
       class="nav-link"
       href=#Results 
       id="Results"
         >Results</a></li>
<li><a 
       class="nav-link" 
       href=#Pricing 
       id="Pricing">
  Pricing</a></li>
    </ul>
```

```
nav > ul {
  display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
.navbar{
    width: 100%;
    position: static;
    z-index: 1;    
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

z index makes sure it stays on top, static makes sure it's static to the div,
width 100% make sure it's always the maximum length

Comment: Your answer was very helpful, thanks :)
I have another question if it's okay, I am not sure how to use code snippet in the small replies.

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: if my answer to this question was helpful please upvote it. then if you write another question on here send me the link to it and I'll do the best I can to answer that too

Comment: Okay I can only post a question every 90 minutes, thanks.